# dynamically add a set of DIVs inside another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

CSS is not really my thing and when I see position relative, static or absolute my head starts to spin :(

So the question is: I have a DIV and inside it I need to put an arbitrary number of `<div>`s aligned **horizontally**. This will be done in runtime since I dont know the amount of DIVs nor the width for each one at design time.
For example lets say I have the following array of DIVs to add:

```
_aDIVs = [[40, '#red'], [10, '#green'], [40, '#blue'], [10, '#brown']];
```

- First DIV needs to fill from 0% to 40% of parent DIV and the BG color is red
- Second from 41% to 50% with BG color green
- Third from 51% to 90%, blue
- Fourth from 91% to 100%, brown

Each DIV will have a different background color, the % are know only at runtime. It's  important to use % because otherwise the filling will break when the browser window re-sizes. The idea is something like this:

```
|--------------------- PARENT DIV ---------------------|

|------RED------||-GREEN-||-----BLUE-----||-BROWN-|
```

(sorry for my drawing skills!)

Right now, the parent DIV is using position absolute, here's the exact declaration:

```
div id="slider-addon" style="height: 5px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; background-color: red; ">
```

I don't care if there is an obscure trick where the first DIV fill 100% but then it get overlapped by the next `<div>` and so on, as long the trick is cross-browser compatible (need to work on IE, FF & Chrome)

Also, if there is a way to have multiple background colors horizontally aligned on the parent DIV that will accomplish the same effect as long as the fill % can be specified.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Solved with ShankarSangoli method, here's the solution with a minor correction:

var _aDIVs = [[40, '#3399FF'], [10, '#33CC33'], [40, '#FFCC00'], [10, '#CC66FF']];

var $sliderDiv = $("#slider-addon");

$.each(_aDIVs, function(i, val) {

```
$sliderDiv.append(

        $('<div></div>').css({ 'float': 'left', 'width': val[0] + '%', 
              'background-color': val[1], 'height': '5' })

);
```

});

Thank you :)

Comment: [Here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a great page about div position that I refer to

Comment: What is your question? Are you having trouble aligning the divs on one line rather than on top of each other? If so you need to use display:inline; in the style for each child div

Comment: Question is, given the "_aDIVs" how do I put the DIVs inside the parent "slider-addon" so they show as described.

Comment: I started reading the suggested site before I posted my question... by the 4 tab (where the author mix relative & absolute) I'm already lost. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This will only work if your values add up to 100, i.e., they are percentages.  If you can't guarantee that, you'll need another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple background colors to any element. To accomplish your goal you can try something like this. To set the background color and other styles you can use css as below

```
#red{
  background-color: red;
}

#blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

var $sliderDiv = $("#slider-addon");
var sliderWidth = $sliderDiv.width();

$.each(_aDivs, function(i, val){
   $sliderDiv.append($(val[1]).css({float:"left":width:parseInt((sliderWidth*val[0])/100)+"%"}));
});
```

Comment: Looks very promising, Im trying to make it work since $.each is not iterating the array

Comment: Make sure the array is well formed and there are no js errors on the page.

Comment: uh...... you don't need to calc anything as far as I can see... did you see my jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes you are correct, there's no need to calc since the "float left"

Comment: I cant vote up yet (not enough rep.) but I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/d4Yft/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="foo" style="width: 100px;">
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 25px; height: 15px; display: inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 15px; width: 15px; display: inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green; height: 15px; width: 20px; display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

Use "display:inline-block;" for the child divs.

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/XDwNa/

Comment: I don't know the amount of DIVs nor the width % at design time.

Comment: You'll probably want two loops then:  one to go through and add up to get the total value.  The second loop will take each div's individual value, divide by the total to get the width in a percentage of the parent div.

Comment: You don't want to declare `i` twice within the same scope. Just declare it once beside `var total - 0;` and set its value inside each loop. Giving each loop a separate iterator would be less confusing.